# Diffraction through a thick aperture

Tags: optics

In normal textbooks, only 2-dimensional apertures are considered. What if we had, let's say, a rectangular aperture with a certain thickness. How would the diffraction pattern be different?

Comment: The light will diffract at both sides of the edges of the screen; in between it will propagate as in any tube it would. Check out how TEM/TE/TM modes diffract at the end of an open ended waveguide.

Comment: The general case of diffraction can be seen applied to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_scattering_techniques